# Delete multiple files from sftp folder in ODI

Tags: sftp

I try to delete multiple files on sftp folder but get the errors.

command:

```
CWD /exceltodb
DELE jobmain*.xls
```

error:

```
ODI-1595: The command script failed with trace 
250 Directory successfully changed. (line=1)
550 Delete operation failed. (line=2)
```

Comment: `CWD`, `DELE`, `250` and `550` are **FTP** commands and response codes. Not **SFTP**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting this using the OdiSftp tool within ODI GUI toolbox, try entering a new line for each command within the "Command to execute" parameter such as:

CWD /exceltodb

DELE jobmain*.xls

Comment: OP enters each command separately. The post was just badly formatted.